# Exception- Unable to get value for numeric field value in jasper report in java class

Tags: mongodb

net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Unable to get value for field 'prd_qty' of class 'java.lang.Integer'

Comment: give us what you trying

Comment: [{
 
 "prd_qty": 2,
 "ord_ship_v": 0,
 "to_org_postal_code": "176310",
 "ord_type": "301",
 "orderQtyDisc": 0,
 "prd_ctgr": 11619,
 "prd_prc_allc": 0,
 "fm_manage_inventory": false,
 "skuCode": "",
 "prd_multi_factor": null,
 "bankers": "",
 "tax_system": "VAT",
 "orderRef": "12929"
 
},
{
 "orgImage": {
  
 },
 "hasImage": "false"
}]